# Ionic 2 destroy previous pages while navigating

Tags: ionic-framework, navigation

I'm creating an Ionic 2 application to run on the IOS environment. My application has resource heavy pages and when navigating between pages using the ionic NavController, the application get stuck towards the latter part of the navigation. After analyzing I realized that it is because the NavController stacking the previous pages in it's memory. Is there a mechanism to destroy the previous pages when navigating forward in Ionic.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.navCtrl.push(newPage).then(() => {
  let index = this.navCtrl.length;
  this.navCtrl.remove(index - 2);
  // index is your stack size
  // index - 1 is your newly pushed page
  // index - 2 is the page previous to it
});
```